# How to display different error message with Python functions

Tags: python

My code works correctly except I would like to display the appropriate error message. For example, if the script can't connect to Consul, I want to display an error stating this. On the other hand, if the key (Jira ticket number) doesn't exist within Consul, I want it to display a different message.

**Function to get key/value from Consul**

```
def getDeployList(jira_ticket):
    try:
        c = consul.Consul(config.get('consul','consul_server'))
        modules=[]
        module_key=[]
        index, data = c.kv.get('deploylist/'+jira_ticket,  recurse=True)
        if data:
            for s in data:
                if s['Value'] is not None:
                    key = s['Key'].split('/')[2]
                    modules.append(key + " - " + s['Value'])
                    module_key.append(key)
            return (module_key,modules)
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False
```

**Function that runs (snippet)**

```
def deployme(obj):
    try:
        module_key,modules = getDeployList(jira_ticket)
    except Exception:
        quit()
```

**Main (snippet)**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        job = beanstalk.reserve()
        try:
            deployme(decode_json)
        except:
            print "There's an issue retrieving the JIRA ticket!"
        job.delete()
```

Comment: It exits the function. The script continuously polls Beanstalk for jobs. If it can't connect to Consul or retrieve the key, it continues to delete the job and monitors the queue for more jobs.

Comment: I would be surprised if there were not exceptions in the lib that you could  catch that were specific to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @idjaw: `quit()` is a built-in interpreter-helper function.  It is an instance of the `Quitter` class which is what `exit()` is an instance of.

Comment: Is this the lib https://github.com/gmr/consulate/blob/master/consulate/exceptions.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already catching your exception in `deployme`. So in your main you will never catch the exception you are looking for. Instead, what you want to do is `raise` so you can catch something.

Also, as @gill made it clear in their comment, since your errors are most likely happening in your `getDeployList` method, you should raise there and remove the try/except from deployme. This will allow you keep that quit, and if any call to `getDeployList` raises, it will be caught in your `__main__` code.

Also, create a custom exception (or raise an exception from the module you are using):

```
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    pass
```

Raise your custom exception in your `getDeployList` method:

```
def getDeployList(jira_ticket):
    # logic
    raise MyCustomException()

def deployme(obj):
    module_key,modules = getDeployList(jira_ticket)
```

Then you catch your exception in main. It should work

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        deployme(decode_json)
    except MyCustomException:
        print "There's an issue retrieving the JIRA ticket!"
```

Comment: I should've been more clear in my original post. So I needed the `quit()` method in order to continue with the program. I have more code that processes after the `try/except` within the `deployme` function. This script continuously monitors a beanstalk queue. I do not want it to exit the program, only the function. I've updated my original post.

Comment: @luckytaxi Then maybe you need to be raising your exception somewhere else? The was your code is implemented in your `__main__`, a `raise` will be needed to get to that print error.

Comment: I think the proper place to raise is in `getDeployList` because OP says s/he expects different errors there (hence the question in the first place). Catching a broad `Exception` in `deployme` will lose that information.

Comment: @gill You are absolutely right. Which means that there should not be a try except in deployme. I'll update my answer.